# Powershell invoke-sqlcmd "select query_hash"

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm trying to build a small tool in Powershell to select some data. One of the things I would like to get out is the `query_hash`, but when I do this with Powershell its not returning the same value as in SQL Management Studio.

In SQL Management Studio it shows like `0xFFCEA347FBFC247D7` but Powershell shows it like this `{50, 123, 144, 118...}`

Anybody who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing, in principle. Management Studio formats `BINARY` values as hexstrings, PowerShell shows you a rendition of a `byte[]`. You can use something like `[BitConverter]::ToString($b).Replace("-","")` if you want a hexstring in PowerShell as well, or else directly in the query for consistency (`CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), value, 1)`).

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.